# Find best combination of two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to find the best combination of two columns in the given schema:

Table Name: `Sales`

Columns: `price, zip_code, color`

In this example, I would like to find the **Highest amount of sales** (determined by price) based on the best combination of `zip_code` and `color`.

In all of the queries, I have tried, it seems to make a really long loop and just finds all the combinations of the attributes.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Edit:

Data:

```
 price  |  zip_code | color
--------+-----------+--------
    11  |   1455    |   red
--------+-----------+--------
    2   |   1455    |   red
--------+-----------+--------
    12  |   1452    |   blue
--------+-----------+--------
    3   |   1451    |   pink
--------+-----------+--------
    4   |   1455    |   pink
--------+-----------+--------
```

Desired Result:

```
price   |  zip_code | color
--------+-----------+--------
   13   |   1455    |   red
```

Comment: Post some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: What if there are ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want only one row row -- even when there are ties -- then `group by` and `limit` suffice:

```
select zip_code, color, sum(price) as total_sales
from Sales
group by zip_code, color
order by total_sales desc
limit 1;
```

If you want all the top rows, then a bit more logic is needed:

```
with zc as (
      select zip_code, color, sum(price) as total_sales
      from Sales
      group by zip_code, color
     )
select zc.*
from zc
where zc.total_sales = (select max(zc2.total_sales) from zc zc2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to take the sum of all sales by zip code and color and then select the top row of your new table, ordered by total sales in descending order.  This looks like:

```
Select zip_code, color, sum(price) as total_sales
From Sales
Group by zip_code, color
Order by total_sales desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Sqlite doesn't use that TOP N syntax, btw.